# Flutter: Execution failed for task ':agora_rtc_engine:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, flutter, agora.io, jitpack, flutter-3.0

I am working on an old project. It worked fine before 5 days ago. Now I am facing an error with agora. I didn't any change on my previous code.
here is error-

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':agora_rtc_engine:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':agora_rtc_engine:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find native-full-sdk-3.4.6.jar (com.github.agorabuilder:native-full-sdk:3.4.6).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://www.jitpack.io/com/github/agorabuilder/native-full-sdk/3.4.6/native-full-sdk-3.4.6.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 38s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             40.0s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I am using   `agora_rtc_engine: ^3.3.1` bacause this project developed without null-safety (maybe flutter 1.5). How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

1.Run **flutter upgrade** in the terminal to upgrade Flutter

2.Run **dart migrate** to run the dart migration tool

3.Solve all errors which the migration tool shows

4.Run **flutter pub outdated --mode=null-safety** to print all outdated packages

5.Run **flutter pub upgrade --null-safety** to upgrade all packages automatically

6.Check the code for errors and solve them

7.Run **dart migrate** again and it should now be successful. Follow the link to checkout the proposed changes

8.Press the "Apply Migration" button

9.Check the code for errors again and fix them.

Run flutter run in the command line and the application should run...

Note: If there are any library in you project that don't support null safety you must need to upgrade that library. if that library don’t have null safety remove the library and use another library

Answer (score 1):

So you have to migrate your project to null-safety first and then get

```
agora_rtc_engine: ^4.2.2
```

Then you to to your build.gradle and add that last line

```
  allprojects {
       repositories {
         google()
         jcenter()
    // add this line.
         maven { url ‘https://www.jitpack.io' }
        }
    }
```

Because following this issue here on [GitHub](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Agora-Flutter-SDK/issues/650#issuecomment-1113503053) there is no solution for it because this issue has been closed on the agora project.

Comment: @Dezel not working. same error again

Comment: Do flutter clean after you add it and try again.
Also what version of flutter are you using?

Comment: I clean and build but not working. and I am using mavencenter, not jcenter.
I am using FVM for this project. tried  2.2.2, 2.10.5, 3.0.0, 30.1 also.

Comment: I editted my answer, you have to migrate to null safety

PS: it's just the last line you have to add.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is still facing this issue

1: Run **flutter pub outdated --mode=null-safety** to check which dependencies are outdated

2: Run **flutter pub upgrade --null-safety** to upgrade all dependencies

3: It would update **agora_rtc_engine** to latest sdk, try to change that to **agora_rtc_engine: 4.2.2**

4: Set **ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'**  in **build.gradle*

Note: If you face any incompatibility with other packages for setting minSdk as 19, change minSdk to 19

5: If you faced any gradle error, you might need to change **gradle-wrapper.properties**

//add this line
**distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.1-all.zip**

Thats all